# Value set by h:selectOneMenu is null in f:ajax listener method

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to use AJAX in my JSF 2.0 web application and have a problem with getting current value from selectOneMenu.

Part of my JSF page.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<h:outputLabel value="Appendix number" for="appendix" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="appendix" value="#{indexMBean.appendix}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Point 1" itemValue="1" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Point 2" itemValue="2" />
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{indexMBean.setHazardsByAppendix}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

setHazardsByAppendix is a procedure in indexMBean. Then the procedure fires I try to get the current value of h:selectOneMenu for passing it on another procedure.

```
public void setHazardsByAppendix() {
    Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    logger.warning(this.appendix);
    this.setHazards(this.hazardSessionBean.getHazardByAppendix(this.appendix));
}
```

But the current value of field appendix is always null. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the type of appendix?

Comment: Show your `@ManagedBean` class declaration and all annotation imports. I suspect that you are not using a valid JSF managed bean scope annotation on it and it thus defaults to `@NoneScoped` (i.e. it get reconstructed on every single `#{}` call). Debugging the `setAppendix()` method should confirm this. If the value is set, but it becomes `null` in the listener method, then you know enough.

Comment: BalusC, thank for your answer. I can't show the code right now, I'm at home now not at work. But I can say that the bean is annotated as @SessionBean.

Comment: mrembisz, the type is String.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in a very strange way. I created a new netbeans project with the same sources. And amazingly it works fine.
It's a really strange but it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
   `<f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{templateSearchHandler.OnDefNameSelect}">
 void setHazardsByAppendix(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    logger.warning(this.appendix);
    this.setHazards(this.hazardSessionBean.getHazardByAppendix(this.appendix));
}`
```

Comment: How does this solve the concrete problem? You are not explaining the concrete problem in any way.

Comment: In you controller listnersetHazardsByAppendix(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) than you got current value in  <h:selectOneMenu id="appendix" value="#{indexMBean.appendix}"> appendix varable by calling

Comment: I still don't see how that **explains** the problem the OP is facing and how exactly that solves the problem. The OP has posted legitimately valid code so far.

Answer (score -1):

This code calls AjaxBehaviour event and pass value to controller through Ajax.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<h:outputLabel value="Appendix number" for="appendix" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="appendix" value="#{indexMBean.appendix}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Point 1" itemValue="1" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Point 2" itemValue="2" />
<f:ajax execute="@this"listener="#{indexMBean.setHazardsByAppendix}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
//Controller
public void setHazardsByAppendix(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    logger.warning(this.appendix);
    this.setHazards(this.hazardSessionBean.getHazardByAppendix(this.appendix));
}
```